# What is the 'Relationship' field for in Android Contacts?

Tags: contacts, google-account, google-contacts, profiles

In Android Contacts, you can add a field called relationships.

What is it used for and does anyone even bother putting it in?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is meant for [your relationship with contact](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/4584610?hl=en)

> After a relationship is added, you can call, text, or email the person using their nickname.... After the nickname is added, you can contact them by saying things like "Text my sister" or "Email my mom."

Some typical fields from Google contacts app in screenshot (you can define a custom field too)

[image]

In example below, I have added child with nickname of XYZ. If I use Google assistant I would say call XYZ

[image]

Comment: I saw this but it didn't work for me. Can you give example what do I actually put under nickname and under relationship?

Comment: Probably your contacts app doesn't support it. I use Google contacts and you can see in edited answer typical fields

Comment: I've done this but when I say 'Call Wife', it looks for all contacts which has the word wife in it. I have unfortunately labelled some of my contact as 'Wife John-Sarah', 'Wife Peter-Kate'. Anyway really appreciate the pictures you've put in.

Comment: the label field can be custom. it is (would be) enough for relation to oneself, i mean, to the phone owner. so, why is the relationship field? as i see, there are also other label fields of other fields, like additional explanation. so, seems, the relationship field can be filled with name, or full name, of another person, who is better known for the phone owner, and the corresponding "label" "subfield" should explain who is the better known person for the contact being edited.

Comment: in my currently used version of the contacts the "relationship" field from the screenshot above, with three dots icon, is named "related person".